# generalized Koszul algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let A be a positively graded algebra such that A_0 has finite global dimension (see "On a common generalization of Koszul duality and tilting equivalence" by Dag Madsen, arXiv.org > math > arXiv:1007.3282)

I am not an expert in this kind of algebras but is it true that, like in the classical case of Koszul algebras, the generalized Koszul algebras are of finite global dimension?

In the classical case where A_0 is semisimple (or of global dimension zero) we have that the global dimension of A is finite.

What happens in the generalized case? Does the same property hold, namely that the global dimension of A is again finite?

Comment: Please spell my name correctly :) and the global dimension of $A$ does not have to be finite, neither in the classical nor the generalized case.

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect spelling.

Comment: But in the thesis "Tilting objects in derived categories of equivariant sheaves" (Christopher Ira Brav) Theorem 4.2.3 claims that in the classical case when A is locally finite and A is noetherian then A has finite global dimension.

Comment: With the same assumptions maybe there is finite global dimension in the generalized case?

Comment: For example the exterior algebra of a vector space $V$ is Koszul and self-injective, so of infinite global dimension.

Comment: Could be, but I'm not sure exactly what the assumptions should be.

Comment: Here is where the global dimension comes into play in the classical case: For $B$ Koszul, $B$ (resp. $B^!$) finite dimensional iff $B^!$ (resp. $B$) has finite global dimension.  May be this is the thing you are looking for?

Comment: That is exactely what I am looking for.

Comment: My question is now if this holds for the generalized Koszul algebra: A generalized Koszul is of finite global dimension iff the dual is finite dimensional ?

Comment: That might be true, but I don't think I ever proved that. (One direction is clear.) For instance in my *Advances* paper you refer to, in Theorem 4.3.4 I added the assumption $\rm{gldim} \; \Gamma < \infty$. I remember discussing this point with some other mathematicians.